# Try to jsfiddle parallax image header seen on here: http://soworldwide.org/

Tags: jquery, parallax

I try to jsfiddle the imageheader parallax-effect seen on the website from http://soworldwide.org/. Now i would like to fade out / and in the big headline when start scrolling. But the Headline disappears hard, and only fades back in smooth… How can i fade it also when disappearing ?

http://jsfiddle.net/NQHmw/3/

---

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

       if($(window).scrollTop()<20){
             $('.headline').stop(true,true).fadeIn("slow");
       } else {
             $('.headline').stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow");
       }
    });
```

Comment: Please update the title of your question to actually match the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a 2 year old question but stop() function was blocking the fade in / fade out effect on text. Check it our here:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop()<20){
     //$('.headline').stop(true,true).fadeIn("slow");
     $('.headline').fadeIn("slow");
   } else {
     //$('.headline').stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow");
     $('.headline').fadeOut("slow");
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NQHmw/60/